# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'

Tags: python, numpy, module, scipy

I want to write a program which performs a periodogram on a series of measurement values listed in the file 'flux.txt' but I get the error:

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'testing'
```

The error also appears if I comment the whole code. I tried to update numpy but it's still updated. May someone help me please?

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open('flux.txt','r') as f:
    item = f.readlines
    print(item)
    signal.periodogram(item)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: How did you install numpy? Ubuntu?

Comment: Check your file folder for potential namespace conflicts (packages which numpy tries to import versus your *.py names overlapping can cause such errors).

Comment: I have the Anaconda distribution on windows. The numpy package it's included

Comment: Then numpy.testing should be there. I just did the same on my box, and np.testing exists.

Comment: By the way, there are many other errors in your program. For instance, `item = f.readlines` assigns a function object to `item`. To assign the result of calling the function to `item`, use `item = f.readlines()`. Then you would need to parse the strings into numbers. Probably easier to use `arr = np.genfromtxt('flux.txt')`, but the details of how to parse or how to use `genfromtxt` depend on the format of `flux.txt`.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your installation. You can look here for more info: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11400

Comment: Thank's to everyone for the help. It seems there are no  namespace conflict. I'll try to reinstall all the packages. The problem is arrived when I installed the scipy package

Comment: The problem has been solved by removing the scipy package I had installed before, maybe it was in conflict with the already existing one. However, now I get the error: module 'scipy.signal' has no attribute 'periodogram'. I think there's still something wrong in the packages